# Add "All Posts" button to custom post taxonomy filter with ajax in wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, ajax

Does somebody know how to add "All Posts" button to my custom post ("albums") with custom taxonomy ("album_category")? I can see my categories (Mixing, Mastering, Production) and when I click on them it shows me the posts that have been ticked under the certain category (Mixing, Mastering, Production). What I want is to have also a button "All Posts" so the user can go back to displaying all posts, once he has viewed the filtered posts.

I know that I can do that with wp_list_categories(array('show_option_all' => "All Posts")); But I don't know how to implement it into the code.

Here is my full code:

My album-page.php

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'albums',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$tax = 'album_category';
$terms = get_terms( $tax );
$count = count( $terms );

if ( $count > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="post-tags">
    <?php
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $tax );
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter" title="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
    } ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<div class="tagged-posts">
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
    <div class="tagged-posts">
        <h2>No posts found</h2>
    </div>
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</article>
```

My functions.php:

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
    // Enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/src/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', 'jquery', null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

    wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
          'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
          'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );
  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

  // Script for getting posts
  function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

    // Verify nonce
    if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
      die('Permission denied');

    $taxonomy = $_POST['album_category'];

    // WP Query
    $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
      'post_type' => 'albums',
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );

    // If taxonomy is not set, remove key from array and get all posts
    if( !$taxonomy ) {
      unset( $args['album_category'] );
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

      $output  = '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
      $output .= get_the_excerpt();

      $result = 'success';

    endwhile; else:
      $output = '<h2>No posts found</h2>';
      $result = 'fail';
    endif;

    $response = json_encode($output);
    echo $response;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

My ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tax-filter').click( function(event) {

        // Prevent defualt action - opening tag page
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        // Get tag slug from title attirbute
        var selecetd_taxonomy = $(this).attr('title');

        $('.tagged-posts').fadeOut();

        data = {
            action: 'filter_posts',
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
            taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {
                $('.tagged-posts').html( data );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( XMLHttpRequest );
            },
            error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( MLHttpRequest );
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( errorThrown );
                $('.tagged-posts').html( 'No posts found' );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
            }
        })

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code there is 2-3 mistake in **js file datatype** and **function file query parameter**.
Below I paste an updated code, please check and let me know incase of any doubts.

Your **album-page.php**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'albums',//Custom Post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$tax = 'album_category';//Custom post type taxonomy name
$terms = get_terms($tax);
$count = count($terms);

if ($count > 0):
    ?>
    <div class="post-tags">
        <?php
        echo '<a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="">All</a> ';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $term_link = get_term_link($term, $tax);
            echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter" title="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
endif;
if ($query->have_posts()):
    ?>
    <div class="tagged-posts">
    <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>
    <div class="tagged-posts">
        <h2>No posts found</h2>
    </div>
<?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Your **functions.php**

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
    // Enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/src/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', 'jquery', null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

    wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
          'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
          'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );
  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);
// Script for getting posts
function ajax_filter_get_posts($taxonomy) {
    // Verify nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['afp_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce'))
        die('Permission denied');
    $taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];
    // WP Query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'albums',//Custom Post type name
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    if (!empty($taxonomy)) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'album_category',//Custom post type taxonomy name
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $taxonomy,
            ),
        );
    }
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
    ?>
    <div class="tagged-posts">
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

Your **ajax.js**

```
jQuery('.tax-filter').click(function (event) {
        // Prevent defualt action - opening tag page
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
        // Get tag slug from title attirbute
        var selecetd_taxonomy = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.tagged-posts').fadeOut();
        var data = {
            action: 'filter_posts',
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
            taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy,
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',//Return type is html
            url: afp_vars.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $('.tagged-posts').html(data);
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            },
            error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(MLHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                $('.tagged-posts').html('No posts found');
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
            }
        })

    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't see where do you add a category that includes all posts. For example like wp_list_categories() has 'show_option_all'. I want to implement it into my code, and I don't know how.

Comment: I added a link above $terms foreach loop in album-page.php 

echo '<a href="#" class="tax-filter" title="">All</a> ';

Comment: this solution works ?

Comment: yes, thank you. I made it work

Comment: @SaraTeofilova If my answer give you a solution then please upvote my answer.